# Facebook Graph API and Group Membership

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Trying to find some information on how to invite someone to a facebook group.  The doco seems to imply that you can only invite someone to a facebook group that the app has created and for a member that is already given permissions to the app, and that they must be an admin/developer/tester for the group.

This sounds really limiting, so more than anything just looking to see if anyone has done this and are my assertions correct?

Comment: yes, your assertions are correct. after all, what's written in the docs is usually correct ;) - no group invite spamming possible with the API, luckily.

Comment: Thanks @luschn - is there a way then to do some verification against a custom database (though the FB API) to confirm that a group member who applies for membership is allowed?  I looked for an appropriate web hook with no success.

Comment: no, there is no such thing